# OpenVPN configuration file

Tags: configuration, openvpn

Can I use the OpenVPN client to connect to a VPN Network using the settings here: http://luchthaven.tudelft.nl/engels/vpn.htm

If the answer is yes, how should the config file look?

Thanks!

Comment: Windows? Please retag or write it in the description.

Answer (score 1):

No. This uses vanilla ipsec (i.e. ipsec+isakmp), while OpenVPN uses SSL + ipsec. They say they only support Cisco's VPN client, why don't you use that?

Comment: Cisco's client does not work on Windows 7 x64

Comment: Try windows' built in IPSEC support?

Comment: I cannot find any support for Group Name in the Win7 VPN

Answer (score 0):

Try [vpnc](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/) much nicer then the Cisco suppled client.

Comment: Works on Windows just with Cygwin ?